# How get updated state in produce of immer

Tags: reactjs, redux, immer.js

Consider the following reducer:

```
const initialBaseTestState = {
  oldValue: "String",
  something: "String two",
};

const baseTest = produce((state = initialBaseTestState, action) => {
const { type, data } = action;
switch (type) {
 case SET_VALUE: {
  state.newValue = "test";
  sendUpdatedState(original(state)); // Send updated state  
  return state;
}
```

Code of function sendUpdatedState:

```
export const updateMonthlyTotalPrice = updatedState => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  console.log(updatedState); 
  // Getting: {oldValue: "String", something: "String two"} 
  // Requiring: {oldValue: "String", something: "String two", newValue: "test"} 
  const string = updatedState.newValue + "s";  
  dispatch(setSomeValueAction(string));
};
```

I know when the `original` is called with 'old' state, so why I am getting the `initialBaseTestState`. Is it some approach to get already updated `state` after the `state.newValue` is updated in `produce`.

NOTE: I would like to keep using the Immer

Answer (score 0):

Solution can be:

```
      const originalState = original(state);
      const newState = {
        ...originalState,
           newValue: "test"
        },
      };
```

Is a better way how to do it?